# Ms Access - Trouble converting a String field to Date field

Tags: ms-access, vba

After importing a File from Excel to Access via VBA,
I am trying to ALTER a String Field which contains Dates into a Date Field using

```
"ALTER TABLE tablex ALTER COLUMN StartDate DATE"
```

String 29/08/2013 in Excel gets Converted into Date 08/29/2013 in Access but

String 9/08/2013  in Excel gets Converted into Date  8/09/2013 in Access

I understand its with the formatting of the Date. Would like to know the correct SQL to execute to get both the formats same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access the default date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`. Therefore before changing data type of the column you **have to disambiguate date values** by swapping `dd` and `mm` parts.

```sql
UPDATE tablex 
   SET StartDate =  MID(StartDate, IIF(Len(StartDate) = 9, 3, 4), 2) + '/' + 
                   LEFT(StartDate, IIF(Len(StartDate) = 9, 1, 2)) +
                    MID(StartDate, IIF(Len(StartDate) = 9, 5, 6))
```

If day part is always two digits then just

```sql
UPDATE tablex 
   SET StartDate =  MID(StartDate, 4) + '/' + 
                   LEFT(StartDate, 2) +
                    MID(StartDate, 6)
```

Comment: Did it help? DO you need more help with your question?

Comment: 9/08/2013 is actually 09/08/2013 in the Field. So the Len Function always returns 10

Comment: Then you should've mentioned it in your question, because an example given by you says otherwise. See the updated answer for the simplified query. Other then that did it help to convert date values?

Comment: Sorry for incorrectly mentioning it. Dates are really Dirty. MID(StartDate, 4) is the MID Function. To which function does the , 2) after MID belong to. Because there is a SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: "UPDATE tablex   SET columny = DateSerial(MID(StartDate,7,4) , LEFT(StartDate,2),MID(StartDate, 4,2))"  I used this SQL.  Thanks @peterm